# Customise AdMob to only display apps Ads on my android app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I added AdMob sdk to my android application.

And all set perfectly. Now, I am looking to filter ads to only display apps adds.

Now, its displaying links to websites too. What can I do.

Comment: There is no way to do this as the accepted answer says. you either stick with it or search for other ads providers. if your app is a game. I once found a games provider ads. but your app must be a game.

Comment: Thanks , yes my app is a game and is targeted at children and I think children would be more interested in games..

Comment: what about an upvote then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

And why would you want to limit ads to only show those for apps. It would be reducing potential revenue for you.